# getting 6 pics on one line

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to have multiple lines of pictures with 6 pics in each line. Currently there are 4 pics on each line and I am not sure how to make it so I have 6. Any help would be very appreciated!

Here is my code:

```php
<?php 

$pageTitle = "Bright Punch Love";
$section = "home";
include('inc/products.php');

?>

<?php include('inc/header.php'); ?>

<div id="top"><img src="top.png" width="1337"></div>

<div class="shirts">

    <ul class= "shirts-section">
        <?php
        foreach($products as $product_id => $product) { 
            echo "<li>";
            echo '<a href="shirt.php?id=' . $product_id . '">';
            echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '" width= 200 alt="' . $product["name"] . '">';
            echo '<p id="details">$30 View Details</p>';
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</li>";
        }   
        ?>
    </ul>

</div>

<?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>

<div id="bottom-index"><img src="bottom-index.png" width="1337"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `%` instead of `px`. Also you use the `width` tag. Try to avoid using css in your html code. Use `class="..."` instead and include your css file in the `head` tag. I make the file now in the head, because it is easier for you. But I would recommend to make an file just for the css.

```php
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .picture{
            width : 15%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

echo '<img src="' . $product["img"] . '" class=\"picture\" alt="' . $product["name"] . '">';
```

Comment: well I meant to use width : 15%;

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's array_chunk function to short your answer. Just Try.

```
$products_new = array_chunk($products, 6);
foreach($products_new as $product_id => $product) {

//Your code

}
```